# Teamcity to Jenkins Migration

Tags: jenkins, migration, teamcity

We are planning to migrate Teamcity to Jenkins due to cost reasons. However we found that conceptually both tools are same but the technical functionality is different. Hence if somebody has experience or has done this migration before, please share the steps (high level) which can help us to plan the migration effectively.

Additionally, Is there a automated or faster way to do the migration?

Thanks